# Node js: Wait for 100 requests to get completed

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code. It iterates over a set of ids and makes a request for each id.I want to execute some code once all the requests are completed - say 100. How can this be done?

```
function initRequest(url){
  request.get(topPostsUrl, function(err,response,body){
    if(err) throw err;
    handlePosts(body);
  })
}

function handlePosts(posts){
  var postsArray = JSON.parse(posts);
  for(var i=0; i < postsCount; i++){
      var targetUrl = itemUrl.replace("**id**", postsArray[i]);
      request.get(targetUrl, function(err,response,body){
        if(err) throw err;
        processOutput(body,i+1);
      })
    }
}

function calthisFunctionAfterAllRequests () {

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to throttle the amount of active requests? Your program may look like an attack to the site you're making your requests to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 disadvantages with Promise.all:

1. If any of promise fails they will all fail (your function to process succeeded requests is not called).
2. All your requests start immediately. If you have an array of 100 urls then you will make 100 requests and possibly make the target of your requests unhappy or lock up network traffic for the machine it's running on.

To address point 1 you can create an array of promises that will handle the reject (fail) and return a `Fail` object. When processing the results you can filter out the failed requests:

```
const doRequest = url => 
  new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) =>
      request.get(
        url, 
        (err,response,body) =>
          (err)
            ? reject(err)
            : resolve(body)
      )
  );
const Fail = function(reason){ this.reason = reason; }
const handlePosts = posts =>
  Promise.all(
    (JSON.parse(posts))
    .map(
      post => post.replace("**id**", post)
    )
    .map(
      url => doRequest(url)
      .then(
        resolve=>resolve
        ,reject => new Fail(reject) //do not fail all requests just because one failed
      )
    )
  )

doRequest(topPostsUrl)
.then(
  handlePosts
)
.then(
  // you can filter out failed request by: results.filter(r=>(r && r.constructor)!==Fail)
  // you can filter out succeeded request by: results.filter(r=>(r && r.constructor)===Fail)
  calthisFunctionAfterAllRequests
)
```

Point 2 can be dealt with by [throttling](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/lib/blob/master/src/index.js#L216-L265) the amount of active requests: the code above would look something like this:

```
const max5 = throttle(5)
const handlePosts = posts =>
  Promise.all(
    (JSON.parse(posts))
    .map(
      post => post.replace("**id**", post)
    )
    .map(
      url => max5(doRequest)(url)
      .then(
        resolve=>resolve
        ,reject => new Fail(reject) //do not fail all requests just because one failed
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution it to use Promises([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)) and `Promise.all`([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) function to wait for all requests.

```
function initRequest(url){
  request.get(topPostsUrl, function(err,response,body){
    if(err) throw err;
    handlePosts(body).then(calthisFunctionAfterAllRequests);
  })
}
function doRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get(url, function(err,response,body){
      if(err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(body);
    })
  })
}
function handlePosts(posts){
  var postsArray = JSON.parse(posts);
  var requests = [];
  for(var i=0; i < postsCount; i++) {
      var targetUrl = itemUrl.replace("**id**", postsArray[i]);
      requests.push(doRequest(targetUrl));
  }
  // here is magic
  return Promise.all(requests)
}

function calthisFunctionAfterAllRequests (requestsResult) {
    // results store in requestsResult array in same order they added
}
```

Comment: I was thinking in the right direction. Was not really sure about how to use Promise.all without having names of the promises.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save request-promise
```

then

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

function initRequest(url){
  rp.get(topPostsUrl)
    .then(body => {
        handlePosts(body)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err
    })
}



function handlePosts(posts){
  var postsArray = JSON.parse(posts)
  var arrayRequests = []
  for(var i=0; i < postsCount; i++){
    var targetUrl = itemUrl.replace("**id**", postsArray[i])
    arrayRequests.push(
        function(){
            return rp
                .get(targetUrl)
                .then(() => {
                    return true
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    throw err
                })
        }
    )
    new Promise
        .all(arrayRequests)
        .then(() => {
            calthisFunctionAfterAllRequests()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw err
        })
  }
}

function calthisFunctionAfterAllRequests () {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the abstract code representation.

```
function RequestAll() {

  for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    initRequest();
  }
  // return a promise 
}


RequestAll.then(function() {
  //whatever you need to do
});
```